# CPI and time of command execution calculation problem

Tags: time, architecture, cpu, execution

A cpu has Clock Cycle equal to 2ns. The execution of arithetics/logical commands demands 4 cycles, execution of branching commands demands 4 cycles and memory access commands 5 cycles. If the frequency of appearance of this types of commands is 40%, 25%, 35% respectively. How much is the average CPI and how much is the average time of command execution?

Comment: What is your problem with this question? The solution is just a weighted average requiring only trivial maths. Can you precise what you do not understand? (and the last question is probably the average time of an *instruction*)

Comment: I don't know if my answer is correct, I calculated the CPI to be (4*40/100 + 4*25/100 + 5*35/100) / 3 = 4.35/3 = 1.45 CPI
And the average time of instruction exec is CPI * CC = 2.9

Comment: No it is not. You cannot have an average CPI of 1.4 with instructions that last all 4 or 5 cycles. Probably the average will be between 4 and 5.